# I am trying to create a mongoDB database using python but when i try to run it in terminal it shows the image in the link provided below

Tags: python, mongodb

My code is:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client['xyz']
collection = db['abc']
dictonary = {'name': 'xyz', 'marks': 77}
collection._insert_one(dictonary)
```

[Check this image for more info about error, as you can see it is showing that screen about how do you want to open this file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUYmx.png)